# Swift UITableview Cell Checkmark and Search not working

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to create `UITableview` with `custom cell` and `sections`. Here, I am trying to do `checkmark` selection at a time `one cell` also If user click section, under the section all relevant row should show check mark like a group selection. Its not working properly. Also, Search one of the major complex into this scenario. Provide some idea to fix this.

Below code I am using,

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myCellLabel: UILabel!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) { // Check Mark Selection Not Properly Working
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    // These strings will be the data for the table view cells
    let sectionNames = ["pizza", "deep dish pizza", "calzone"]
    let data = [["Margarita", "BBQ Chicken", "Pepperoni"],
                ["sausage", "meat lovers", "veggie lovers"],
                ["sausage", "chicken pesto", "prawns", "mushrooms"]]

   //var filteredData: [[String]]!
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    var searchController : UISearchController!
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //filteredData = data
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 78.5
    }


    @IBAction func searchAction(_ sender: Any) {

        // Create the search controller and specify that it should present its results in this same view
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        // Set any properties (in this case, don't hide the nav bar and don't show the emoji keyboard option)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3118804693, green: 0.435135603, blue: 0.9917090535, alpha: 1)
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

        // Make this class the delegate and present the search
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // MARk: - Tableview Delegates
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.myCellLabel.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionNames[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedValue = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        //send selectedValue to server...
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) { // SEARCH NOT WORKING

        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
                return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            })
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest solution to try is to have the UITableViewDataSource methods use `filteredData` not `data`. Assign the `filteredData` to `data` during initialization.

Comment: @AgRizzo I applied filteredData but now I am getting error in updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) function this line return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil - Error: Value of type '[String]' has no member 'range'

Comment: @kjoe sorry I cant get you. Lol Just now I came stack. who asked about this? if its really same plz provide link.

Comment: just now deleted the question but since i made a answer for that to i'm goin to aste here too and perhasp adapt to you model or suggest do the new model

Comment: @kjoe Thanks you

Comment: are you gonna parse a json for the answer, have you the model for that json, why section description are in separated array?

Comment: @kjoe Yes. I am going to parse the JSON. Before that I need to learn how to do that. above code working everything except search and cell selection not showing properly. Just let me know why its happening and what I did mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

Add this line to where its commented it out.

`var filteredData: [[String]] = data`

Then change your UITableViewDatasource methods to use `filteredData` and not `data`. For example

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return filteredData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredData[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.myCellLabel.text = filteredData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

---

`data` should only be used in the search delegate function.

Comment: Yes I did it but its showing Error in updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) function - At  this line return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil - Error: Value of type '[String]' has no member 'range'

Comment: @app ok-- solve that problem then. This is how to get the tableview to show the filtered results.

Comment: I tried my best. If I know solution why I am here. I am facing that issue if you know the solution provide me.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to adopt these struct for your model

```
struct MyData {
    var value: String?
    var selected: Bool = false
}
struct tableData{
    var sectionName: String
    var data: [MyData]
}
```

these struct would hold both section names and seleccion in cells. in your class cahnge like this your model:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchController : UISearchController!
    var rowNames = [tableData]()

    var filteredData: [tableData]!
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //filteredData = rowNames
    }


    //MARK: List Tableview
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return rowNames.count
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return rowNames[section].sectionName
}
```

since you are reusing the same tableview for the search, you must check what data source use, if the searchbar is active but no input yet avaible then don't reload data

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchController.searchBar.text != nil && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
            return filteredData.count
        }else{
            return rowNames.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! CustomCell
        if searchController.searchBar.text != nil && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
             cell.NameLabel.text = filteredData[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row].value
        }else{
            cell.NameLabel.text =  rowNames[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row].value
            cell.accesotytype = rowNames[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row].selected ? .checkmark : .none
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        if searchController.searchBar.text == nil || searchController.searchBar.text == ""{
            if rowNames[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row].selected == true{
                cell?.accessoryType = .none
                rowNames[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row].selected = false
            }else{
                cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
                rowNames[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row].selected = true
            }
        }

        //self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    //MARK: Search Delegate

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text, searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            //maybe betters and faster way to make the search, even not keep the section name in the search IDK but that's unto you
            for row in rowNames{
             let value = row.data.filter({
                    $0.value!.contains(searchText)
                }).map({$0})
                let val = tableData(sectionName: row.sectionName, data: value)
                filteredData.append(val)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

PD: there is one thing missing here, how to select all row when tapin on header, but thas for another question that you should make.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great example. Btw I have one doubt why we need to give *var selected: Bool = false* because we can persist selected cell locally right ?

Comment: if cell selection comes from server that will make problems, because same API we will use different platforms. Can you please change it? If you don't mind

Comment: no we persit the state of the cell and when scrol the cell check for the state, also miss in the cell forRow method.

Comment: the selecte state does not come from server is just localy as said, when you scroll the tableview and is being reused your previuos selection is lost, soyou mus keep a track of it to show the righ values, unless you tableVIew is too small that does not scrool at all, or even is you want to persit the selection in disk o any other way an recover later, by the way is the answer is good for you accept it.

Comment: I am sorry. I am confused here, Why we need to use like this var selected: Bool = false? if I use this I have to get from server same kind of value also when it goes true, I have to update the server?

Comment: without this var selected: Bool = false. how to achieve my scenario?

Comment: another array and have a map of the index of selected, but the simple way is the bool var

Comment: I am sorry. I am need to done without that  var selected: Bool = false. If I add this additional data we have to add into server.

Comment: man you dont see it in the struct, this is not necesary added to the server since this struct can conform to codable beacuse you are asining a value by defaul is always false.